# Text going off the view

Tags: swiftui, view

When I have a long line of text such as this: `SpaceX completed its fourth operational commercial crew mission to the International Space Station Oct. 14 with the safe return of a Crew Dragon spacecraft with four American and European astronauts on board.` The text will fall off of the screen, looking at photo 2 below. I've tried to restrain it, but then I get the `...` and cannot see the rest of the text, the first image that I had included.

Here is the code:

```
VStack {
    Text("SpaceX completed its fourth operational commercial crew mission to the International Space Station Oct. 14 with the safe return of a Crew Dragon spacecraft with four American and European astronauts on board.")
        .padding()
}
```

[image: text trails off the screen]

[image: text gets cut off by the screen]

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . The code you show does not.

Comment: I updated, sorry i forgot.

Comment: I think the issue is from your image, may I see your image's code?

Comment: Your code does not reproduces your issue. 
Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same phenomenon cannot be reproduced through the code example you gave us. Maybe it's causing problems in other parts of your project.

The solution I thought of is to limit the width of Frame of `VStack` or `Text` by the size of the screen to prevent it from leaving.

```
        VStack {
            Text("SpaceX completed its fourth operational commercial crew mission to the International Space Station Oct. 14 with the safe return of a Crew Dragon spacecraft with four American and European astronauts on board.")
                .padding()
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `.multilineTextAlignment(.center)` to `Text` view

```swift
VStack {
    Text("SpaceX completed its fourth operational commercial crew mission to the International Space Station Oct. 14 with the safe return of a Crew Dragon spacecraft with four American and European astronauts on board.")
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .padding()
}
```